# Using feather icons with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, icons

I am trying to use [feather icons](https://github.com/feathericons/feather#feather) within my react app. So far I have added the following to my index.html file

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
<script>
  feather.replace()
</script>
```

And then I included composed a button with a feather icon in one of my component files:

```
<li className="nav-item">
   <a className="nav-link" href="#">
       <span data-feather="settings"></span>
         Settings
   </a>
</li>
```

But the icon still doesn't show up. I am new to React, was there something I did wrong with regard to importing feather icon into my component file?

Answer (score 7):

One easy way to use Feather with React is to use the `react-feather` library. The GitHub repo has more information about how to use it: https://github.com/carmelopullara/react-feather

Answer (score 3):

Don't edit the HTML file then you use React.

Install react-feather library:

```
npm install react-feather
```

Make new React Component like **LogOutButton.js** :

```
 import { LogOut } from 'react-feather';

    const LogOutButton = ({logOutUser}) =>
          <span onClick= {()=> logOutUser()}>
              <LogOut color='#ffffff' size="24" /> // <--- your icon
          </span>
    
 export default LogOutButton
```

Answer (score 2):

Install the plugin/package as mentioned by @Serhii

Then you can do the ff:

```
import { Gear } from 'react-feather';
...
<li className="nav-item">
   <a className="nav-link" href="#">
       <Gear />
       Settings
   </a>
</li>
```

ps.
Gear is a dummy name. Please search for appropriate icon for the your task.

Comment: Best and straightforward approach

Answer (score 1):

Try React **react-feather library**

**install using npm**

```
npm install react-feather
```

**Usage**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Camera } from 'react-feather';

const App = () => {
  return <Camera />
};

export default App;
```

Refer [feathericons.com](https://feathericons.com) for Icons

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer not to include another library into your code base, you can take advantage of a `useEffect` hook to replace the feather icons, as shown below:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import * as feather from 'feather-icons/dist/feather.min';

export function MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    feather.replace();
  }, []);

 return(
  <span data-feather="plus"></span>
 );
};
```

Note that `feather.replace()` may not be the most computationally efficient way to do this, so use caution if you have a lot of feather items in your DOM.